# How to check for an specific string within a customized function for a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I got the next pandas dataframe column:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

d = {'Name': ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris','Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'Heikkinen, Miss.Laina']}

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am trying to decode this column, if `Mrs` is found in the string row then return `is_married`, else `not_married`:

```
    def is_married_female(raw_df):
         raw_df['Name'].str.contains('Mrs').any():
            return 'married'
         else:
            return 'not_married'
        
    raw_df['is_married_female']=raw_df.apply(lambda x: is_married_female(x["Name"]), axis=1)
```

However I keep getting the next error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Expected Output could look like this:

```
raw_df['is_married_female']

# not_married
# married
# not_married
```

What am I missing in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue:

`x['Name']` is a python [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) not a Series or a DataFrame.

Inside the function `is_married_female` the variable `raw_df` is a string like:

> 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'

When `raw_df['Name']` is run this is equivalent to:

```
print('Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'['Name']) # TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Which is trying to access the string via index, like

```
print('Braund, Mr. Owen Harris'[0]) # B
```

Fix:

1. Treat the function parameter as its correct type (`str`) and use [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in).
2. Rename `raw_df` to `name` to avoid future confusion

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris',
              'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)',
              'Heikkinen, Miss.Laina']}

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def is_married_female(name):
    if 'Mrs' in name:
        return 'married'
    else:
        return 'not_married'


raw_df['is_married_female'] = raw_df.apply(
    lambda x: is_married_female(x["Name"]),
    axis=1
)

print(raw_df.to_string())
```

---

A more performant solution, however, would be to use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris',
              'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)',
              'Heikkinen, Miss.Laina']}

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

raw_df['is_married_female'] = np.where(raw_df['Name'].str.contains('Mrs'),
                                       'married', 'not_married')

print(raw_df.to_string())
```

---

Output for both is:

```
                                                  Name is_married_female
0                              Braund, Mr. Owen Harris       not_married
1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)           married
2                                Heikkinen, Miss.Laina       not_married
```